# how to make this background running code terminate with just one kill command?

Tags: c, linux, signals, kill, terminate

I'm trying to make a sudden exit handler that allows the program to free up memory before finally exiting. While my code partially works, it doesn't work as intended. What I expect it to do is run the `end_app()` function when I execute `killall a.out` to kill the running program in the linux 
command line.

Below is a screenshot of what happened at my console when I typed in the commands that are in quotes (excluding the quotation marks). I deliberately changed the real prompt name to `linux-prompt#` for simplicity.

```
linux-prompt# "./a.out &"
[1] 6071
linux-prompt# Started
"ps -A | grep a.out"
6071 pts/2    00:00:11 a.out
linux-prompt# "killall a.out"
linux-prompt# Ending
Ended
"ps -A | grep a.out"
6071 pts/2    00:00:30 a.out
linux-prompt# "killall a.out"
linux-prompt# "ps -A | grep a.out"
[1]+  Terminated              ./a.out
linux-prompt# "killall a.out"
a.out: no process killed
linux-prompt# "ps -A | grep a.out"
linux-prompt#
```

I was actually expecting a "a.out: no process killed" after executing "killall a.out" the second time, not the third time.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
    #include <signal.h>

    static char*x=NULL;

    void end_app(int s){
      printf("Ending\n");
      struct sigaction si;
      si.sa_handler=SIG_DFL;
      si.sa_flags=0;
      sigaction(SIGCHLD,&si,NULL);
      sigaction(SIGTSTP,&si,NULL);
      sigaction(SIGTTOU,&si,NULL);
      sigaction(SIGTTIN,&si,NULL);
      sigaction(SIGSEGV,&si,NULL);
      sigaction(SIGTERM,&si,NULL);
      sigaction(SIGHUP,&si,NULL);
      free(x);
      printf("Ended\n");
    }


int main(){
      struct sigaction s,si;
      si.sa_handler=SIG_IGN;
      si.sa_flags=0;
      s.sa_handler=end_app;
      s.sa_flags=0;
      sigaction(SIGCHLD,&si,NULL);
      sigaction(SIGTSTP,&si,NULL);
      sigaction(SIGTTOU,&si,NULL);
      sigaction(SIGTTIN,&si,NULL);
      if (sigaction(SIGSEGV,&s,NULL)==-1){printf("Cant trap signal!\n");return 1;}
      if (sigaction(SIGTERM,&s,NULL)==-1){printf("Cant trap signal!\n");return 1;}
      if (sigaction(SIGHUP,&s,NULL)==-1){printf("Cant trap signal!\n");return 1;}
      unsigned long n=10000005;
      x=calloc(1,n);
      printf("Started\n");
      while(1){
        //do random daemon work here
      }
      return 0;
    }
```

What could I be doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

To clarify, what I'm doing is compiling the above program using gcc, then the file a.out is created in the current folder as the actual program itself.

I run one instance of it in the background by typing `./a.out &`

the `main()` function then executes forever as intended.

When I execute `killall a.out` the `end_app()` function is supposed to execute once only then the program is removed from memory then officially terminates. The problem I have is that I have to execute `killall a.out` two times to end the program instead of `killall a.out` only once.

I'm trying to make it so that executing `killall a.out` only once will terminate the program similar to what I described in the previous paragraph.

Comment: Your question is somehow confused. Its answer is probably simple, the hardness of writing it is to understand your problem. I would suggest to try to make your problem more clear.

Comment: I updated my question to reflect what is supposed to happen and what steps to take to make it happen.

Comment: Once you exit the OS reclaims all the memory.  You don't really need to do this.

Comment: I can't trust that. I need to free the memory but I figured it out. I had to set a static variable in my program that is to be set by my signal handler and then I have to detect it from within my program.

Answer (score 2):

You can use pkill command to kill all the process.

Example:-

You have 5 a.out running in background.

$ pkill -9  a.out

Using pkill -9 a.out, This will kill all the a.out process.

Comment: I already know how to execute killing programs from the linux command-line. What I wanted to do which I already figured out is to make my program execute the signal handler properly and then fully terminate when a user executes the kill command.